# Need to re-declare the base class member functions in derived class in generic programming

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, inheritance, c++14

I have two generic classes (Stack and Queue) , And As most of the function names of Stack(Asssume its the base class ) can be re-used and i would have seperate logic for these functions in Stack And Queue

```
#ifndef STACK_H
#define STACK_H
template<class T>
class myStack{
private:
    T *s;
    int top,s_size;
public:
    myStack(int k=40);
    ~myStack();
    void push(T x);
    T pop();
    int isEmpty();
    int isFull();
    T peek();
    void display();
};
#endif // STACK_H
```

And below is the queue class header file

```
#ifndef MYQUEUE_H
#define MYQUEUE_H
#include "stack.h"


template <class T>
class myQueue : public myStack<T>
{
    private:
        int f,r;
    public:
        void push(T x);
        int isEmpty();
        int isFull();
        void display();
        myQueue(int k=40);
        T del();
        T last();
        T first();
        virtual ~myQueue();

};

#endif // MYQUEUE_H
```

Its apparent that i have re declared  the below functions without which my code is failing to compile, Is it really needed to re declare them in the derived class to have a seperate logic or can i just use those functions in derived class without having them in header, as the functions are already inherited

```
        int isEmpty();
        int isFull();
        void display();
```

Below is the error encountered, if  i do not re declare them in derived class

```
||=== Build: Debug in Data_Structures (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
C:\Users\xprk569\Data_Structures\src\myQueue.cpp|13|error: no 'void myQueue<T>::display()' member function declared in class 'myQueue<T>'|
C:\Users\xprk569\Data_Structures\src\myQueue.cpp|34|error: no 'void myQueue<T>::push(T)' member function declared in class 'myQueue<T>'|
C:\Users\xprk569\Data_Structures\src\myQueue.cpp|41|error: no 'int myQueue<T>::isEmpty()' member function declared in class 'myQueue<T>'|
C:\Users\xprk569\Data_Structures\src\myQueue.cpp|46|error: no 'int myQueue<T>::isFull()' member function declared in class 'myQueue<T>'|
||=== Build failed: 4 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|
```

Comment: You mean you are redefining `isEmpty` for `myQueue` without declaring it in `myQueue`?

Comment: @holt yes, excatly

Answer (score 1):

If you want to **redefine** a method for a child class, you need to redeclare it, the following does not work:

```
struct A {
    void foo () { }
};

struct B: public A { };

// error: no 'void B::foo()' member function declared in class 'B'
void B::foo () { }
```

Also note that if you want to make use of polymorphism (**override** the base method), you need to make your method virtual:

```
struct A {
    virtual void foo () { }
};

struct B: public A {
    virtual void foo ();
};

void B::foo () { }
```

The c++11 introduced a new [`override`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/override) keyword that you can use to check if you are really overriding:

```
struct A {
  void foo () { }
};

struct B: public A {
  // error: 'void B::foo()' marked 'override', but does not override
  void foo () override { }
};
```